# How to audit whether the gems in my Rails app are threadsafe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thread-safety

Is there an automated way to determine which gems in my Gemfile are threadsafe? Perhaps there exists a catalog about which gems are threadsafe?

For example, say I have a Rails app and am auditing whether its dependencies are threadsafe.

The best approach I can think of, other than researching each gem manually, is to run a static analysis tool like Rubocop over all my gems (eg: `rubocop -r rubocop-thread_safety --only ThreadSafety,Style/GlobalVars,Style/ClassVars,Style/MutableConstant`). But even Rubocop isn't guaranteed to catch all thread-safety bugs.

Could there be a better way?